# Using sed to perform substitutions in a file

Tags: sed, replace

I was trying to replace dates in a huge file using sed. I tried :

```
sed -ie 's/2014-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/2014-05-07/g' test
```

However, nothing happened at all, my file test is not modified. Do you know what I am missing here ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `sed` uses [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).  In BRE, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)` act like ordinary characters.  As such, you'd need to escape the `{` and `}`:

```
sed -i 's/2014-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/2014-05-07/g' test
```

You would not need to escape those if using extended regular expressions, i.e.

```
sed -r -i 's/2014-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/2014-05-07/g' test
```

The `-r` option for `sed` denotes ERE:

```
   -r, --regexp-extended

          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

Moreover, using `-e` is redundant in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the curly brackets:

```
sed -ie 's/2014-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/2014-05-07/g' test
```

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
echo "foo 2014-01-01 bar" | sed -r 's/2014-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/2014-05-07/g'
```

or

```
echo "foo 2014-01-01 bar" | sed 's/2014-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/2014-05-07/g'
```